# Sphinx autosummary: create a summary of a module

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, numpydoc

I am having trouble getting sphinx to create a summary table for modules. I have added `sphinx.ext.autosummary` to my `conf.py` file and I am using `numpydoc`.  Sphinx seems to create the summary table for attributes and methods on a class, but it does not create a summary table for the module that contains the class.

I created a minimal working example (MWE) to test this out. The MWE project just has an `__init__.py` and which imports `generic_module`. The contents of `generic_module` are:

```
def foo(a, b):
    """
    Adds a + b
    """
    return(a+b)

def bar(a, b):
    """
    Subtracts a + b
    """
    return(a-b)

class onetwo(object):
    """
    Adds 1 or 2
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.whatever = 1

    def one(self, a):
        """
        Adds one to a
        """
        return(a + 1)

    def two(self,a):
        """
        Adds two o a
        """
        return(a + 2)
```

Sphinx auto documents `foo`, `bar`, and `onetwo`. It also creates a nice summary of the methods on `onetwo`.  However, it does not create a summary table at the top of the page for `generic_module`.

I know that I can add `.. autosummary::` to my `generic_module.rst` file, as documented [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html).  However, I have to list each and every function on my module to get that to work.  I would think the `autosummary` extension could do this for me.